# JS Как найти определенное значение в объекте?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как найти первое совпадение у которого значение ключа true ? В качестве примера вот такой объект

```
let state = {
  whichPopupToShow: {
    infoPopup: false,
    ranksPopup: true,
    categoriesPopup: false,
    sizePopup: true,
  }
}
```

Как в консоль получить `ranksPopup` и дальше не проверять объект...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let state = {
  whichPopupToShow: {
    infoPopup: false,
    ranksPopup: true,
    categoriesPopup: false,
    sizePopup: true,
  }
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(state.whichPopupToShow)) {
  if (value) {
    console.log(key);
    break;
  }
}
```